# How to check equality in a SQL table rows?

Tags: sql

Right now I'm working on some beginner SQL stuff and I've run into a problem with a practice question:

> List the SSN, name (first and last) and salary of all employees that
>   are managers. 
>  Hint: Use a nested query to obtain the answer.

A manager is someone who has the same SUPERSSN as their SSN. The above question seems straight forward enough to me but when I run my SQL code:

```
SELECT SSN, FName, LName, Salary
FROM employee
WHERE SSN = SuperSSN
```

It returns ZERO rows, and I'm not sure why. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT!: My mistake. The SuperSSN was varChar whereas the SSN was Int.

EDIT2: The table looks something like this:

```
SSN   BDate     Sex Address Salary  FName   Minit   LName   DNo SuperSSN
123456789 | 1965-01-09  | M |   "731 Fondren, Houston, TX"  | 30000 |   John    B | Smith | 5 | 123456789
```

Comment: Can you provide sample table data.
Are SSN and SuperSSN belongs to same table?

Comment: If you solved the problem, post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted, else, provide us the information mentioned above so we can help you, please

Comment: @GGG I haven't figured it out yet, but I did post a sample value from the table

Comment: Weird, I just your select and it worked perfectly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to keep the `SuperSSN` column of type `VARCHAR`, you can try this:

```
SELECT SSN, FName, LName, Salary
  FROM employee
 WHERE SSN = (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(SuperSSN AS UNSIGNED) FROM employee WHERE SSN = SSN);
```

Else, simply this would do it:

```
SELECT SSN, FName, LName, Salary
  FROM employee
 WHERE SSN = (SELECT DISTINCT SuperSSN FROM employee WHERE SSN = SSN);
```

Comment: I get the error "Subquery returns more than one row" :( thanks for the help though

Comment: @JohnathanScott: Ive made minor edits. Please check now.

Comment: You can't return more than one value in a subquery when you're using it on a WHEN clause

Comment: You are a beautiful person, thank you soooo much! :)

Comment: This can return possible non-managers as the SSN has to be exactly the same as the SuperSSN, with your query you're just checking if any employee has the employee's SSN as their SuperSSN.

Comment: @GGG: Somehow that line slipped out of my eyes. Changed now.

Comment: Do `IN (SELECT ...` instead of that un-safe `= (SELECT ...`!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
SELECT SSN, FName, LName, Salary
FROM employee
WHERE SSN = (SELECT SuperSSN FROM employee WHERE SSN = SSN)
```

Comment: Thanks (also, by what the question marks as a manager, the accepted answer will possibly return non-managers since it'll simply list all SuperSSNs and check if the SSN of the employee is on it)

Comment: Do `IN (SELECT ...` instead of that un-safe `= (SELECT ...`!

Comment: But the SuperSSN has to be exactly the same as the SSN, doing an `IN (SELECT ...` could return invalid results as I already stated before.